# Allow only specific subdirectories on .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have some NuGet packages and I need to push some files that are on the build directory, the problem is that github default gitignore for VisualStudio ignores all subdirectories in packages directory.

```
/packages/SomePackage/build/ <-- Allow
/packages/SomePackage/OtherDirectory/ <-- Ignore
/packages/OtherPackage/AnotherDirectory/ <-- Ignore
```

In .gitignore I have this:

```
**/packages/*
!**/packages/**/build/
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I am not clear on yet, you have to follow the following order to ignore everything under packages except what is under build directory:

```
packages/*
!packages/d1/
packages/d1/*
!packages/d1/build/
```

This is inspired from the example in the man page of gitignore. Also note that files already tracked by Git are not affected! To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use `git rm --cached`.

**Update**: Maybe this is the answer (quoted from man page of gitignore):

> It is not possible to re-include a file if
>              a parent directory of that file is excluded.